# Incremental for loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a hard time understanding for loops in Python.
I have the following code in Javascript (Modolus 11 test) I want to convert to Python:

```
    var secNumber = this.dob + lastDigits;
    var factors = [4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

    for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
      sum += secNumber.substring(i, i + 1) * factors[i];
    }

    // modulus 11 test
    return sum % 11 !== 0 ? false : true;
```

What would the Python equivalent be ?

Comment: What will you be doing with `i` and `sum`?

Comment: can you show how ur string will look like???

Comment: String = "0411994545"

Comment: what is content of factors???

Comment: @Seya: please add that to your question, as well as a sample `factors` and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python uses [for each loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), so iterating over *numbers* would require you to produce a sequence of numbers first. Python uses the [`range()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) for this:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(len(factors)):
    pass
```

Note that `sum` is assigned `0` explicitly, separately.

**Usually** however, you'd just loop over objects directly, rather than generate indices:

```
sum = 0
for element in factors:
    pass
```

But if you are summing the factors, just use the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
total = sum(factors)
```

Note that I avoided using the name `sum` there to avoid masking the built-in function.

To multiply bytes from a sequence of bytes, just [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the bytes and factors together:

```
sum = 0
for byte, factor in zip(string, factors):
    sum += byte * factor
```

which can be collapsed with `sum()` and a generator expression:

```
total = sum(byte * factor for byte, factor in zip(string, factors))
```

This only works if `string` is a [`bytes` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), not a [Unicode `str` string object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str); `bytes` objects are really sequences of integers in the range 0-255.

If you wanted to interpret the characters as *digits*, use a Unicode string and use `int()` to convert each to an integer:

```
total = sum(int(digit) * factor for digit, factor in zip(string, factors))
```

Demo of the latter with the sample input you provided:

```
>>> sec_number = '0411994545'
>>> factors = [4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> sum(int(digit) * factor for digit, factor in zip(string, factors))
164
>>> total = sum(int(digit) * factor for digit, factor in zip(string, factors))
>>> total % 11 == 0
False
```

Note that the `==` test already produces a boolean; there is no need to use a conditional expression in Python to produce a boolean result.

Answer (score 2):

read about documentation of for in python:

```
 for i in range(len(factors)):
     # do stuff
```

Note: indexing start from 0 and end one less

demo:

```
>>> [x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I think this is what you want:

```
>>> s="0411994545"
>>> f="1234567894"
>>> sum([int(x)*int(y) for x,y in zip(s,f)])
238

>>> sum([int(s[i])*int(f[i]) for i in range(len(s))])
238
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ssum = sum(int(x) * y for (x, y) in zip(S, factors))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python there is no "traditional" for-loop, but there are many constructs which make loops in Python very powerful:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(str(i))
```

This prints integers from 0 to 9, range creates an iterator with the interval [low, high)

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(str(i))
```

Prints 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 because the steps (third optional parameter are set to 2).

Also you can enumerate through your factors:

```
for key, val in enumerate(factors):
    pass
```

This gets you a key and the corresponding value of each element in factors.

If you do not need keys, than this simply does the job for you:

```
for val in factors:
    # some stuff to do
```

This iterates over every element in factors.

If you need a special condition to be checked, you can use break or continue:

```
for val in factors:
    if val == 0:
        continue # skips one iteration
    elif val == 1:
        break # cancels the whole loop
    else
        # do some stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't strictly have C/Javascript style for loops but prefers a simpler syntax.

The C/JS style for has:

- an *initializer* `var i=0, sum=0`
- a *conditional test*, `i< factors.length`
- an *iterator*, `i++`
- and a task to repeat `sum += string.substring(i, i + 1) * factors[i]`

A pythonic for loop has only a variable and a list or iterable and a task, and looks like this:

```
mysum = 0
for i in range(length):
    mysum += int(strings[i])*factors[i]
```

where range(length) is a built-in function that expands to [0,1,2,3,.., length-1]
and the task consists of the indented block after the colon

In JS strings and numeric types are automatically converted (even when you dont want it), but in Python that is not true.  `int()` converts to integer and `float()` converts to floating point number.